# HTML custom list image center text

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying some customizing of lists and now I am using custom `list-style-image`. The example is in the code snippet. Can someone explain me, how to center the text and the image, so the text is always centered with the image and the image with the text (in case of multi line)? I added a short picture to clarifiy what I want to achieve.
Thanks a lot.
[image: picture]

Code:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=B);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
.list-div li:nth-child(3){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=C);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}

.list-div li:nth-child(4){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=D);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>List item A    
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
          <li>List item B</li>
          <li>List item C</li>
          <li>List item D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `background-position-y: 50%;` to the `li`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
li{
 align-self: center;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
}


.list-div li:nth-child(1){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=B);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
 
}
.list-div li:nth-child(3){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=C);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
 
}

.list-div li:nth-child(4){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=D);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
 
}
.list-div li{
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>List item A    
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
          <li>List item B</li>
          <li>
            <p>Multiple</p>
            <p>Paragraphs</p>
            <p>Works</p>
          </li>
          <li>List item D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what happens if you enter some <p>'s into the first items text?